# What does it mean 'to reference' and what are the requirements of 'coreferentiality' in the context of descriptive grammar?

Tags: grammar, terminology, appositives

I would like to understand exactly what is meant in a grammar discussion when someone uses the word "coreferential".  I understand  it to mean that two or more constituents (e.g. a noun and a noun phrase) must *reference* the same entity, but I'm not really sure what is required for a constituent to be considered a *reference*, as distinct from a description or an ascription.

Consider:

> Jane Doe, **soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **a soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **best soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **the best soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.

Are all of the bolded phrases *coreferential* with "Jane Doe"? Only two of them, the ones with the  article, can clearly stand as the grammatical subject of the verb phrase in that sentence:

> *soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.
>
> *best soprano in the church choir had a bad cold. (marginal?)
>
> a soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.
>
> the best soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.

And of those two, only the latter, the one with the definite article, seems (to me) to yield meaning equivalent to the following:

> Jane Doe had a bad cold.

So, to be "coreferential", does the noun phrase have to *point directly to* the preceding noun, to it uniquely, and be able to stand in its place in the sentence and yield equivalent meaning when so standing, or does it merely have to be *predicable* of the preceding noun?

Comment: This seems like it would be better asked in [linguistics.se], since it's not really about English.

Comment: @Barmar: OK, but the term has been used on this site.

Comment: Is this question about *to reference* or *to refer*?

Comment: A reference refers, so both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that we can expect everyone to use those terms in exactly the same way — especially if you're asking about people discussing English grammar online, who are not always known for using modern linguistic terms precisely and accurately — but for what it's worth, [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) characterizes examples like yours as "ascriptive", and hence as *non*-referential. This is true even of your example with "the best soprano in the church choir", where the same phrase *could* be used to uniquely refer to Jane Doe, but in this case is merely ascribing a characteristic to her.

CGEL gives a few examples in chapter 15 § 5.2 (b), pages 1356–8, such as this one:

> Kim Jones, a quite outstanding student, won a scholarship to MIT.

where it marks the phrase "a quite outstanding student" as ascriptive, comparing it to the identical phrase in a sentence like this one:

> Kim Jones was a quite outstanding student.

(and in fact, in discussing another example it even mentions the ascriptive NP supplement's "predicand").

Admittedly, in the specific passage about ascriptive supplements, CGEL doesn't explicitly use the term "non-referential", nor does it give any examples with the definite article; *however*, the section about ascriptive noun phrases in general (chapter 5, § 8.3 (a), page 402) does both of those things, so I don't think it leaves any ambiguity about this.

Comment: An example. Of what **would** count as coreference in this stricter sense is ***Sally** has learned to tie **her** shoes*, where the shoes’ tier and their possessor are one and the same person. Contrast that with *John has knelt to tie her shoes* or *Jane dawdles when dressing herself, so Sally has learned to tie her shoes*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: Re: "this stricter sense": If you're aware of a broader sense that *would* include the OP's examples, can you post a separate answer about that?

Comment: I meant merely to refer back to the distinction you had ascribed to CGEL between reference, co- or otherwise, and ascription.

Comment: And I hope you appreciate that I just used both *refer* and *ascribed* in metadiscourse about reference and ascription. [He says, patting himself on the back]

Comment: I'm having some device/SE profile issues. Apologies for the late response. I found a discussion recently on the linguistics site on SE where a CGEL example of  **non-referential** was cited. It was in the context of the definite vs indefinite article. Indefinite is clearly ascriptive and non-referential, but the definite can be non-referential too, per CGEL.  The sentence cited was analogous to "*The thief* must have come in through the bathroom window" in the context of an unsolved crime where the identity remains unknown. But I don't accept that distinction. Referentiality is contextual IMO

Comment: @TimR: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. What distinction don't you accept? (But yes, referentiality is contextual: two identical sentences might have a phrase that's referential in one but not the other. It depends on the intended interpretation.)

Comment: What I don't accept is the requirement that the referent be a known, definite entity. In "The perp, whoever it was..", to use another similar example, I would consider "the perp" referential, but they would say it was "non-referential" because the perp's *identity* is indeterminate.

Comment: I just now found the post again (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521025/is-this-clause-restrictive-or-non-restrictive/521040#521040).  See the section on *NPs with an indeterminate interpretation*.

Comment: So I'd say this was a case of apposition, with both NPs being co-referential, despite the fact that "The criminal" is, in their view, indeterminate:  "This criminal, whoever he is, this 'Masked Marauder', will soon be caught and put behind bars."